# Error using receiverandroid

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

This is an extract of my `manifest.xml` file:

```
<receiverandroid:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <actionandroid:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When I compile the code, I get the following error in the Console:

```
Element type "receiverandroid:name" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
```

Isn't this actually what I have done? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Split `receiverandroid` ***to*** `receiver android` (Add a space in between)

Comment: <receiverandroid:name=".SmsReceiver"> should be <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave space in  `<receiverandroid:name` and `<actionandroid:name`

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare your receiver as :

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

currently you combine Tag name and Attributes . make space between tag and attributes